# Vue.js: filter a set of data containing values between 2 floating point values from jQueryUI slider, search keyword, and genre

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, vue.js

I have put together this *Movie listing app* with Vue.js and Axios.

The application displays a  list of movies from themoviedb.org.

The UI slider that can be seen in the toolbar, unlike the by genre filter, is non-functional. It is supposed to *filter movies by rating*.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    movies: [],
    genres: [],
    genreSelected: "all",
    filteredMovies: [],
    loading: true,
    errored: false,
    url: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=10a6546780c9082d52c54eb9c07f5d67&language=en-US&page=1",
    genreUrl: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=10a6546780c9082d52c54eb9c07f5d67&language=en-US",
    search: '',
    page: 1,
    perPage: 12,
    pages: [],
  },
  methods: {
    getGenres() {
      axios.get(this.genreUrl)
        .then(response => {
          this.genres = response.data.genres;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        });
    },
    getMovies() {
      axios
        .get(this.url)
        .then(response => {
          $("#rating_slider").slider({
            range: true,
            step: 0.5,
            min: 1,
            max: 10,
            values: [3, 10],
            animate: "slow",
            orientation: "horizontal",
            slide: function(event, ui) {
              $(this).find('.ui-state-focus').append($(this).find('#amount').show().text(ui.value));
            }
          });
          this.movies = response.data.results;
          this.filteredMovies = response.data.results;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
          this.errored = true
        })
        .finally(() => this.loading = false)
    },
    setPages(movies) {
      this.pages.length = 0;
      var numberOfPages = Math.ceil(movies.length / this.perPage);
      for (var index = 1; index <= numberOfPages; index++) {
        this.pages.push(index);
      }
    },
    paginate(movies) {
      var page = this.page;
      var perPage = this.perPage;
      var from = (page * perPage) - perPage;
      var to = (page * perPage);
      return movies.slice(from, to);
    },
    scrollToTop() {
      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
      }, 250);
      return false;
    },
    getMoviesByGenre() { // To filter movies by selected genre
      this.page = 1; // Show filtered results stating at page one
      if (this.genreSelected !== "all") {
        this.filteredMovies = this.movies.filter(movie => {
          return movie.genre_ids.indexOf(this.genreSelected) > -1;
        });
        this.setPages(this.filteredMovies);
        this.filteredMovies = this.paginate(this.filteredMovies);
        return;
      }
      this.setPages(this.movies);
      this.filteredMovies = this.paginate(this.movies);
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getGenres();
    this.getMovies();
  },
  watch: {
    displayedMovies() {
      this.setPages(this.searchResults);
    }
  },
  computed: {
    displayedMovies() {
      return this.paginate(this.searchResults);
    },
    searchResults() {
      this.page = 1;
      return this.movies.filter((movie) => {
        return movie.title.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase());
      });
    }
  },
  filters: {
    lowercase(value) {
      return value.toLowerCase();
    },
    capitalize(value) {
      return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);
    },
    titlecase(value) {
      return value.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|[\s-/])\w/g, function(match) {
        return match.toUpperCase();
      })
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.input-group {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-group .form-control {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: .375rem .75rem;
  border-radius: .25rem;
}

.input-group-append {
  margin-left: -1px;
  display: flex;
}

.site-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.topbar {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 7px 0 rgba(21, 30, 38, 0.3);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.branding {
  display: flex;
  height: 52px;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#search-bar {
  order: 3;
}

#group-search {
  padding: 0 5px;
}

#group-search input,
#group-search button {
  background: #343a40;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .05);
  color: #e2e2e2;
}

#group-search input {
  border-right: none;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  outline: none !important;
}

#group-search button {
  padding: 0.375rem 1rem;
  border-left: none;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.toolbar {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 10px;
}

#slider-container {
  position: relative;
}

#rating_slider {
  width: 200px;
  background: #fff;
}

#amount {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -24px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: none;
  line-height: 16px;
  width: 36px;
  border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #777;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
}

#amount:after,
#amount:before {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 4px 4px;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  right: auto;
}

#amount:before {
  top: -5px;
  left: 14px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #e2e2e2;
}

#amount:after {
  top: -4px;
  left: 14px;
  border-width: 0 4px 4px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff;
}

.ui-state-focus,
#amount {
  outline: none !important;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.grid .grid-item {
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.grid .video-box {
  position: relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
}

.video-box .photo img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
}

.video-box .info {
  padding: 11px 8px;
  position: relative;
}

.video-box h2 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.video-box .meta {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.1;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  top: -16px;
  background: #b42d3a;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #fff;
}

.video-box .meta::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -10px;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 5px solid;
  border-color: #6e0000 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.video-box .more {
  margin: auto 8px 0 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #1B192F;
}

.video-box .more:hover {
  background: #252438;
}

.video-box .rating {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  right: 5px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #3f51b5;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*Page items*/

.page-item {
  display: inline-block;
}

.site-footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .grid .grid-item {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .site-wrapper {
    padding-top: 60px;
  }
  .topbar {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0px;
    height: 52px;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 5px 0;
  }
  .branding {
    height: 40px;
  }
  .navigation {
    padding: 0;
    position: static;
    order: 3;
  }
  .navigation li {
    height: 42px;
  }
  #search-bar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 767px;
    flex: 1;
  }
  #group-search {
    padding: 0 20px;
  }
  .grid {
    padding-top: 0;
  }
  .grid .grid-item {
    flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
    max-width: 33.333333%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .grid .grid-item {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 479px) {
  .hide-xxs {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="site-wrapper" id="app">
  <div class="topbar bg-dark">
    <a href="#" class="branding">Movies</a>
    <div id="search-bar">
      <div id="group-search" class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control form-control-dark" type="text" name="search" v-model="search" placeholder="Search movies..." aria-label="Search">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn" type="submit" disabled="disabled">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="toolbar rounded-sm clearfix">
      <div class="d-inline-block">
        <p class="my-0 d-inline-block">Filter by genre:</p>
        <!-- Added model and onchange Event -->
        <select name="genres" id="genre_filter" class="d-inline-block" v-model="genreSelected" v-on:change="getMoviesByGenre()">
          <option value="all">All</option>
          <!-- This will be the default option -->
          <option v-for="genre in genres" v-bind:value="genre.id">{{genre.name}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="d-inline-block pl-4" id="slider-container">
        <p class="my-0 pr-3 d-inline-block">Filter by rating:</p>
        <div id="rating_slider" class="d-inline-block">
          <div id="amount">3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid">
      <!-- Replaced displayedMovies with filteredMovies -->
      <div v-for="(movie, index) in filteredMovies" class="grid-item">
        <div class="video-box">
          <div class="photo text-center">
            <img :src="'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500_and_h282_face/' + movie.poster_path" :alt="movie.title">
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <h2>{{movie.title}}</h2>
            <p class="meta">{{movie.release_date}}</p>
            <p class="genres mt-0">Genres:
              <span v-for="(id, index) in movie.genre_ids">{{ index > 0 ? ", "  : "" }}{{ genres.filter(genre => genre.id === id)[0].name }}</span>
            </p>
            <p class="rating m-0">
              <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{movie.vote_average}}
            </p>
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="more">More Info</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="justify-content-center py-3" v-if="!filteredMovies.length">No movies found</div>
    </div>
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
      <ul class="pagination pagination-sm text-center">
        <li class="page-item" @click="scrollToTop">
          <a class="page-link" href="#" @click="page = 1;" aria-label="First">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item" @click="scrollToTop">
          <a class="page-link" href="#" v-if="page != 1" @click="page--;" aria-label="Previous">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&lsaquo;</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item" v-for="pageNumber in pages.slice(page-1, page+2)" :class="{'active': page === pageNumber}" @click="scrollToTop">
          <a class="page-link" href="#" @click="page = pageNumber;">{{pageNumber}}</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item" @click="scrollToTop">
          <a class="page-link" href="#" @click="page++" v-if="page < pages.length" aria-label="Next">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&rsaquo;</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item" @click="scrollToTop">
          <a class="page-link" href="#" @click="page = pages.length;" aria-label="Last">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <footer class="site-footer bg-dark">
    <p class="text-center">&copy; 2019 MyWebsite.com</p>
  </footer>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.18.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

I have not been able to find a way to "capture" the two values of the slider and use them as a filter in the Vue.js part of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use computed method to generate and return filtered list of movies  by using parameters of genre selected, search keywords and rating rage within that same method.

Currently, you have too many methods, but all you need to do is to have one computed method, that will be iterated in template, and updated each time any of properties ( genre, range, search keyword, updated list, pagination ) is changed.

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        movies: [],
        genres: [],
        genreSelected: "all",
        //filteredMovies: [], //this one should be computed
        loading: true,
        errored: false,
        url: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=10a6546780c9082d52c54eb9c07f5d67&language=en-US&page=1",
        genreUrl: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=10a6546780c9082d52c54eb9c07f5d67&language=en-US",
        search: '',
        page: 1,
        perPage: 6, //I have reduced it to lower number due to console outputs in snippet run
        pages: [],
        votesFrom : 1,
        votesTo : 10,
    },
    methods: {
        getGenres() {
            axios.get(this.genreUrl)
                .then(response => {
                    this.genres = response.data.genres;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                });
        },
        getMovies() {
            let self = this;
            axios
                .get(this.url)
                .then(response => {
                    $("#rating_slider").slider({
                        range: true,
                        step: 0.5,
                        min: 1,
                        max: 10,
                        values: [3, 10],
                        animate: "slow",
                        orientation: "horizontal",
                        slide: function(event, ui) {
                            $(this).find('.ui-state-focus').append($(this).find('#amount').show().text(ui.value));
                            self.votesFrom = ui.values[0];
                            self.votesTo = ui.values[1];
                            
                            self.resetPages();

                        }
                    });
                    this.movies = response.data.results;
                    this.setPages(this.nonPaginatedMovies);
                  //  this.filteredMovies = response.data.results;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                    this.errored = true
                })
                .finally(() => this.loading = false)
        },
        setPages(movies) {
            this.pages.length = 0;
            console.log('total movies',movies.length);
           // var numberOfPages = Math.ceil(movies.length / this.perPage);
            this.pages = Math.ceil(movies.length / this.perPage);
          /*  for (var index = 1; index <= numberOfPages; index++) {
                this.pages.push(index);
            }*/
        },
        resetPages(){
            this.page = 1;
            this.setPages(this.nonPaginatedMovies);
        },
        paginate(movies) {
            var page = this.page;
            var perPage = this.perPage;
            var from = (page * perPage) - perPage;
            var to = (page * perPage);
            return movies.slice(from, to);
        },
        scrollToTop() {
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 250);
            return false;
        },
        /*   getMoviesByGenre() { // To filter movies by selected genre
         this.page = 1; // Show filtered results stating at page one
            if (this.genreSelected !== "all") {
                this.filteredMovies = this.movies.filter(movie => {
                    return movie.genre_ids.indexOf(this.genreSelected) > -1;
                });
                this.setPages(this.filteredMovies);
                this.filteredMovies = this.paginate(this.filteredMovies);
                return;
            }
            this.setPages(this.movies);
            this.filteredMovies = this.paginate(this.movies);
        } */
    },
    created() {
        this.getGenres();
        this.getMovies();
    },
    ready(){

    },
    watch: {
       /* displayedMovies() {
            this.setPages(this.searchResults);
        },*/
        search(){ //watching on change, we reset pagination
           this.resetPages()
        },
        genreSelected(){ //on changing genre we reset pagination
            this.resetPages()
        },
        page(){

        },
    },
    computed: {
  /*      displayedMovies() {
            return this.paginate(this.searchResults);
        },*/
       /* searchResults() {
            //this.page = 1;
            return this.movies.filter((movie) => {
                return movie.title.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase());
            });
        },*/
        nonPaginatedMovies(){ //need total movies for pagination
            return this.movies.filter((movie) => {
                let matchesSearch = true;
                let withinRatingRange = true;
                let belongsToGenre = true;


                if(this.search !== ''){
                    matchesSearch = movie.title.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase());

                }

                withinRatingRange = (movie.vote_average >= this.votesFrom && movie.vote_average <= this.votesTo);

                if (this.genreSelected !== "all") {
                    belongsToGenre = movie.genre_ids.indexOf(this.genreSelected) > -1;
                }

                return (matchesSearch && withinRatingRange === true && belongsToGenre === true);

            })
        },
        filteredMovies(){
           return this.paginate(this.nonPaginatedMovies);
        }
    },
    filters: {
        lowercase(value) {
            return value.toLowerCase();
        },
        capitalize(value) {
            return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);
        },
        titlecase(value) {
            return value.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|[\s-/])\w/g, function(match) {
                return match.toUpperCase();
            })
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.input-group {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-group .form-control {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: .375rem .75rem;
  border-radius: .25rem;
}

.input-group-append {
  margin-left: -1px;
  display: flex;
}

.site-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.topbar {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 7px 0 rgba(21, 30, 38, 0.3);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.branding {
  display: flex;
  height: 52px;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#search-bar {
  order: 3;
}

#group-search {
  padding: 0 5px;
}

#group-search input,
#group-search button {
  background: #343a40;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .05);
  color: #e2e2e2;
}

#group-search input {
  border-right: none;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  outline: none !important;
}

#group-search button {
  padding: 0.375rem 1rem;
  border-left: none;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.toolbar {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 10px;
}

#slider-container {
  position: relative;
}

#rating_slider {
  width: 200px;
  background: #fff;
}

#amount {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -24px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: none;
  line-height: 16px;
  width: 36px;
  border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #777;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
}

#amount:after,
#amount:before {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 4px 4px;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  right: auto;
}

#amount:before {
  top: -5px;
  left: 14px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #e2e2e2;
}

#amount:after {
  top: -4px;
  left: 14px;
  border-width: 0 4px 4px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff;
}

.ui-state-focus,
#amount {
  outline: none !important;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.grid .grid-item {
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.grid .video-box {
  position: relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
}

.video-box .photo img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
}

.video-box .info {
  padding: 11px 8px;
  position: relative;
}

.video-box h2 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.video-box .meta {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.1;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  top: -16px;
  background: #b42d3a;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #fff;
}

.video-box .meta::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -10px;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 5px solid;
  border-color: #6e0000 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.video-box .more {
  margin: auto 8px 0 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #1B192F;
}

.video-box .more:hover {
  background: #252438;
}

.video-box .rating {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  right: 5px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #3f51b5;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*Page items*/

.page-item {
  display: inline-block;
}

.site-footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .grid .grid-item {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .site-wrapper {
    padding-top: 60px;
  }
  .topbar {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0px;
    height: 52px;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 5px 0;
  }
  .branding {
    height: 40px;
  }
  .navigation {
    padding: 0;
    position: static;
    order: 3;
  }
  .navigation li {
    height: 42px;
  }
  #search-bar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 767px;
    flex: 1;
  }
  #group-search {
    padding: 0 20px;
  }
  .grid {
    padding-top: 0;
  }
  .grid .grid-item {
    flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
    max-width: 33.333333%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .grid .grid-item {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 479px) {
  .hide-xxs {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="site-wrapper" id="app">
    <div class="topbar bg-dark">
        <a href="#" class="branding">Movies</a>
        <div id="search-bar">
            <div id="group-search" class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control form-control-dark" type="text" name="search" v-model="search" placeholder="Search movies..." aria-label="Search">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn" type="submit" disabled="disabled">
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="toolbar rounded-sm clearfix">
            <div class="d-inline-block">
                <p class="my-0 d-inline-block">Filter by genre:</p>
                <!-- Added model and onchange Event -->
                <select name="genres" id="genre_filter" class="d-inline-block" v-model="genreSelected">
                    <option value="all">All</option>
                    <!-- This will be the default option -->
                    <option v-for="genre in genres" v-bind:value="genre.id">{{genre.name}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="d-inline-block pl-4" id="slider-container">
                <p class="my-0 pr-3 d-inline-block">Filter by rating:</p>
                <div id="rating_slider" class="d-inline-block">
                    <div id="amount">3</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid">
            <!-- Replaced displayedMovies with filteredMovies -->
            <div v-for="(movie, index) in filteredMovies" class="grid-item">
                <div class="video-box">
                    <div class="photo text-center">
                        <img :src="'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500_and_h282_face/' + movie.poster_path" :alt="movie.title">
                    </div>
                    <div class="info">
                        <h2>{{movie.title}}</h2>
                        <p class="meta">{{movie.release_date}}</p>
                        <p class="genres mt-0">Genres:
                            <span v-for="(id, index) in movie.genre_ids">{{ index > 0 ? ", "  : "" }}{{ genres.filter(genre => genre.id === id)[0].name }}</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="rating m-0">
                            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{movie.vote_average}}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="more">More Info</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="justify-content-center py-3" v-if="!filteredMovies.length">No movies found</div>
        </div>
        <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
            <ul class="pagination pagination-sm text-center">
                <li class="page-item" @click="scrollToTop">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" @click="page = 1;" aria-label="First">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item" @click="scrollToTop">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" v-if="page != 1" @click="page--;" aria-label="Previous">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&lsaquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item" v-for="pageNumber in pages" :class="{'active': page === pageNumber}" @click="scrollToTop">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" @click="page = pageNumber;">{{pageNumber}}</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item" @click="scrollToTop">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" @click="page++" v-if="page < pages.length" aria-label="Next">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&rsaquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item" @click="scrollToTop">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" @click="page = pages.length;" aria-label="Last">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <footer class="site-footer bg-dark">
        <p class="text-center">&copy; 2019 MyWebsite.com</p>
    </footer>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.18.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

You will notice that I have commented out some methods, and also no need for `:on-change`, since you can `watch` the model change. 
There are only two computed properties, one for creating pagination, and other with paginated filtered list. 
Also, there is no need to form an array for `this.pages`, VueJS does proper iteration for numbers as well as for arrays and objects.

Comment: How would you achieve this goal?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir, I have edited my answer with code rewritten, it should work well now